# Cordova Android Capture video in a small window / div

Tags: android, cordova, video

So, I am working on an application that needs the capability of using the camera of your android phone in a div, so that the rest of the user interface is visible to the user. Also, I need to hide the controls of the video and provide external controls. The cordova camera plugin does not support this (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#CameraPopoverOptions)
Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following plugin https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin
it is possible to put the camera preview in a html5 canvas.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey Jasper, Thank you! I did find this, but what is your take on the efficiency in this case?

Comment: I personally did not use this plugin; I created my own android and ios plugin, because i needed other stuff to happen in the camerapreview. When looking at the code of this project, I think this is a good and viable way to put a camerapreview in a div without much coding yourself in native languages.

Comment: Fair Enough! Will let you know how it goes

Comment: If this plugin does not work, I think it will be best to write this camera plugin for each platform yourself. (If you know how to develop for each specific platform). I would advice looking at the cordova camera plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera
And extend this code to your requirements.

Comment: Yep, thats the plan! Thank you anyway!